# setTween does't work in ScrollMagic

Tags: jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I just started trying to figure out how GSAP and ScrollMagic work together, and as I follow up the source code in this cool guide site: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_velocity.html , it does not work in my codepen.

Here is mine with intention to scale up 'scene2' after the black line reaching top of the window: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZxZXm

This is how my js looks like:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller
var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement:'#pinned-trigger1',
  duration:$(window).height()-50,
  triggerHook:0,
  reverse:true
}).setPin('#pinned-element1');

//I cannot scale it up here.
    var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#scale-trigger",triggerHook:0, duration: 300})
                .setTween("#fstpin", {borderTop: "30px solid white", backgroundColor: "blue", scale: 4})


controller.addScene([
  scene1,
  scene2
]);
```

and html as following:

```
<main class="full-screen" role="main">
  <section class="full-screen blue ">
    <div id='scale-trigger'></div>
     <div id='fstpin'>
      <div id='scaled-element'>
        <h1>Basic Pin</h1>
        <p>Elements are pinned for their respective pixel value set as the duration and released again.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="pinned-trigger1" class="full-screen orange">
    <div id="pinned-element1">
     <p>This element will be pinned </p>
    </div> 
  </section>

  <section id="pinned-trigger2" class="full-screen red">
    <div id="pinned-element2">
      <p>This element should disapeared</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="full-screen blue">
    <div>
      <p>Section Four!</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Your codepen link is broken.

Comment: @TahirAhmed man thanks a lot! I didn't even notice it! now it's funcitoning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you are missing the `animation.gsap.js` **[dependency](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/docs/animation.GSAP.html)** in order for `ScrollMagic` to work with `TweenMax`.

**[Here](http://codepen.io/tah_med/pen/MKWKBG)** is your forked pen. Take a look at the `Pen Settings` by clicking on `Settings` from the menu (or by clicking on any of the `gear` icons present under each editing panels) and then look at the all the external JS files under the `JavaScript` tab.

Comment: gotcha, I thought 'ScrollMagic.js' and 'TweenMax.min.js' were enough for the animation! Thanks a lot!